# How can I replace a string with a list of other strings?

Tags: python

Is there a way to do this?

```
list = ['test inc', 'abc', '123 corp']
words_to_filter = ['inc', 'corp']
list.replace(words_to_filter,'')
```

my expected result should be:

```
test, abc, 123
```

right now I'm getting:

```
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list
```

Comment: Try iterating over each word in `words_to_filter` and run your `list.replace(word, '')` instead. Better yet, use the `filter()` function

Comment: There's no `list.replace()` method.

Comment: @mmenschig `filter()` doesn't work here.

Comment: Note that your replace will keep the whitespace at the end of your final result so it won't be the exact same string as the output you wished for.

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting that error. You should be getting `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: Do you want to replace strings or whole words? `123 corporation` will become `123 oration`.

Comment: You should not use built-in names like `list` to name your variables since it overwrites the `list()` constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about :

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for word in words_to_filter:
         list[i] = list[i].replace(word, "").strip()
```

As a one liner :

```
list = [" ".join([x for x in item.split() if x not in words_to_filter]) for item in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a dictionary instead of a list.

```
test_str = 'inc test'
  
lookp_dict = {"hi" : "hello", "test" : "untest"}
  
temp = test_str.split()
res = []
for wrd in temp:
    res.append(lookp_dict.get(wrd, wrd))
      
res = ' '.join(res)
  
print(str(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most direct way I can think of to do this:

```
old_list = ['test inc', 'abc', '123 corp']
words_to_filter = ['inc', 'corp']
new_list = [' '.join(w for w in p.split() if w not in words_to_filter) for p in old_list]
new_list
['test', 'abc', '123']
```

The nested list comprehension can be expanded into longer form if you prefer:

```
new_list = []
for phrase in old_list:
    words = [word for word in phrase.split() if word not in words_to_filter]
    new_list.append(' '.join(words))
```

Also note:

- Your original ideal output had `123` as an integer instead of a string `'123'`. If this is what you really want then add another statement `new_list = [int(s) if isdigit(s) else s for s in new_list]`
- You originally used `list` to hold your list. Use something else because `list` is a keyword and it can bite you.